# After jQuery hover, the divs don't come back

Tags: jquery

```
$('.gallery2').hover(function(){

    $('.upperdiv').animate({
        'height':'65px'
    },300);
    $('.lowerdiv').animate({
        'height':'65px',
        'top':'30.4%'
    },300);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.upperdiv,.lowerdiv').fadeOut(300);
});
```

Is there anyone there who could give me some solution for this? When I hover it again the animated divs will not come out.

Comment: can you please post a working JSFiddle example for us to help examine what your issue may be?

Comment: Ok sir.. sorry for not providing you the appropriate codes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chooiii/btruqkjy/1/


please click the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery method `hover` accepts two functions to be executed as arguments, one on the `mouseenter` and one on `mouseleave`

Do not use `fadeOut` withoud `fadeIn` as it not only alters the opacity but also makes the elements inline style `display:none` which needs to be reverted when showing the elements again.

So the jS goes like this :

```
$('.gallery2').hover(function () {
    $('.upperdiv').animate({
        'height': '65px'
    }, 300);
    $('.lowerdiv').animate({
        'height': '65px',
            'top': '30.4%'
    }, 300);
}, function () {
    $('.upperdiv').animate({
        'height': '0px'
    }, 300);
    $('.lowerdiv').animate({
        'height': '0px',
        'top': '54.4%'
    }, 300);
});
```

See the modified version here : http://jsfiddle.net/kj8yfney/1/

Comment: Thnx for the help bro. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Then chose it as the best answer so that it will help others. Just click on the tick! :)

Answer (score 0):

fadeIn/Out animate opacity, whereas you animate height and top props. So when you call fadeOut and fadeIn isn't called, elements would stay invisible.

Comment: ahhh thanks for the info master :). I really appreciate your answer :)